# jmdm. dienen vs. jmdn. bedienen?

Tags: meaning, grammar-identification

Some prefixes (e.g., be-, ver-…) can simply make intransitive verbs transitive. However I’m not sure whether there is a difference in meaning or an obvious usage preference of some verbs over the others either in written or spoken German? Unfortunately I couldn’t find the answer in dictionaries or grammar books.

Examples:

> jmdm. dienen – jmdn. bedienen
>
> jmdm. folgen – jmdn. verfolgen
>
> über jmdn. lächeln – jmdn. belächeln
>
> auf eine Frage antworten –  eine Frage beantworten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recheck your dictionary or find another one: You should always assume that the prefix changes the meaning of a verb or at least give a subtle shift.

For your examples:

> jmdm. dienen – jmdn. bedienen
>   -> to serve someone (as a servant) - wait on someone
>
> jmdm. folgen – jmdn. verfolgen
>   -> follow s.o., in a physical or ideological sense - follow s.o. physically, trail s.o.
>
> über jmdn. lächeln – jmdn. belächeln
>   -> the latter is condescending, the former not
>
> auf eine Frage antworten – eine Frage beantworten
>   -> that’s actually rather close.

Comment: Also note *verdienen, befolgen, verantworten* also exist and mean a completely different thing.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That was really helpful. Some verbs do really have different meanings but they could share a meaning, as in my second example both verbs can convey the idea of physical following as you said, and in my last example both verbs have really close meanings. In this case, is there a preferance for some verbs in spoken or written German? As for my 3rd example, in dictionaries both verbs are defined separately 'sich lustig machen' without comparing them so I couldn't tell that one verb is more condescending than the other.

Comment: *Dieser Hebel auf der Lok **dient** zum Bremsen.* — Der Lokführer **bedient** den Hebel zum Bremsen. In this example, *dienen* tells what the lever is good for, while *bedienen* means someone uses the lever for some action which may be only an example in your mind. In  general, one can say the verbs taking a dative object are more abstract  – even if you use them with a prepositional object.

Comment: About lächeln vs. belächeln, it's again about the level of abstraction. *Ich lächelte über das Missgeschick.* calls for an additional *hinweg* which means *I ignored the mishap with a smile.* while *Ich belächelte das Missgeschick* means exactly the opposite. Because *belächeln* is focusing on its object.

Comment: @Janka Thank you. I found these sentences on the internet: Der Kellner dient dem Gast- Der Gast wird von dem Kellner bedient. I think *folgen* and *verfolgen* can be used to express physical following, is it a matter of style? Which is more common?

Comment: *Der Kellner dient dem Gast.* is about the abstract concept of the waiter servicing "the guest", while *Der Kellner bedient den Gast.* is about a waiter actually doing it. The latter may also be meant as a concept, but not as abstract as the former one.

Comment: @Janka Can I say that the difference between lächeln and belächeln resemble the difference between spotten and verspotten?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84355/discussion-between-janka-and-user).